# 403 error when url size exceeds certain limit when deployed in QA and PROD

Tags: java, jboss, webserver, http-status-code-403

I am having a JSP page with display tag for pagination. There are some data which is getting passed through URL when I switch pages in display tag.

My observation in local system while switching between pages is when the url length is more than 3000 characters, and when I copy the url from the address bar, It is getting trimmed to 2083 characters. But the system works as expected.

But In QA and prod, for the same scenario, I am getting a 403 error.

I am using a IE browser for which [maximum url length is 2083 characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427).

What I suspect is the the jboss server that is used in QA and prod sends out a 403 if the url length is more than a certain limit. Is this possible? I am pretty sure this issue has got some thing to do with the JBOSS server but couldn't figure out exactly what it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange because the 403 error code means forbidden. But as you say, the maximum URL length that internet explorer can handle is 2083, so the URL is truncated (it doesn't seem a JBoss problem).

But if you still want to increase the URL length allowed by JBoss you can try to increase its [maxHttpHeaderSize](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/http.html) (if not specified it's 8192 bytes by default). It can be done in the server.xml of the webserver (in JBoss 5.1 for example it's located in deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml). In this file you've to add the parameter (if it doesn't already exist) in the HTTP or HTTPS connector you use, for example:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" port="8080" address="${jboss.bind.address}" 
       connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"/>
```

But for the information given to you, the problem seems to be directly related to the [URL length limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url) of Internet Explorer.